# Jquery UI Fails on html5 form attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button

Jquery UI buttonset even fails when the html5 `form` [(HTML FORM="")](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_form) attribute is added. The events that our bound aren't working, I haven't dived into jquerys UI source code just yet, I wanted to know if Im making a silly mistake or if it's something small that can be fixed.

Basically, it doesn't remove the 'ui-state-active' class from the previously selected button in the set, thus, rendering it like so:

[image]

Where it should be like this:

[image]

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3D4Ce/3/

Comment: I think it's a bug, you could report to jQueryUI team.

Comment: It would seem odd that a simple attribute on the radio would kill the whole event @andyf, very weird, I've submitted a ticket